# django populate admin listbox field from another model

Tags: django, model, listbox

I have a model field in which staff users can select a value from a list box. I used a fix list and the "choiches" parameter.

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EXERCISES_LIST)
```

where EXERCISE_LIST is a sequence of tuple as required by "choiches" parameter.

Now I would like to give staff users the possibility to create this EXERCISES_LIST by themself using a model, is it possibile? and what happen if they delete an item from the list that is used by a Exercise model record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution:

1. I created another model in models.py only for the name of the exercise:

   class ExerciseName(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       return u'%s' % (self.name)
   ```
2. I modified the original model adding a ForeignKey to ExerciseName

   class Exercise(models.Model):
       member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
       name = models.ForeignKey(ExerciseName)
3. I registered ExerciseName model in admin.py to have the possibility to modify them in a separate admin view.

   admin.site.register(ExerciseName)

So now I'm able to create a new Exercise and to choose its name from another model (ExerciseName).